# Shorter name for "non-blocking with background synchronization?"

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

What would be a short, human name (so that support dude can spell it) for a concept where user action is non-blocking and state is synchronized in the background?

In my case I mark some clients as having really crap network and thus force them into such mode of operation.

Normal mode of operation is on-line, synchronous, blocking, live, soft real-time and ignores cached data.

Modern "offline html5" application do this, ajax does it, unix AIO does it, but what is it called?

Candidates so far

- asynchronous (spelling)
- non-blocking
- offline (unclear)
- batched (incorrect)
- network-challenged ()
- cached (Tomasz)
- delayed
- ...
- ...
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not a tech-poet, but my first thought was also 'asynchronous'.

But, it's not for the innocent, so my second thought would revolve 
around the stem "cache".

So, I'd try:

- locally cached
- offline cached

or, counter-naming: "synchronized" (which we, techies, quickly understand
as "blocking", whereas the simple, honest John has no idea why sunchronization
should block).

So "synchronized" or "local synchronized".

Unfortunately, it's all a matter of taste. More important is the one-sentence
explanation, which the support guy/gal should give the customer...

EDIT: "local synchronized" was again the kind of name we give, which normal 
people cannot understand. It could be, e.g. "synchronized remote".

You may wonder, what the opposite should be? I.e. the synchronous mode for fast
networks? Well, I'd call it "online mode" or some other name that suggests the 
people that they *should* be "online" to use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

**"No signature required delivery"?** (Oh..., that's a little bit long.)